# How to get text from website using expected condition?

Tags: python, automation, pycharm

1. To get any text from website
2. I do not understand how to use this:

- presence_of_element_located
- visibility_of_element_located
- visibility_of
- presence_of_all_elements_located
- text_to_be_present_in_element
- text_to_be_present_in_element_value
- frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it
- invisibility_of_element_located
- element_to_be_clickable
- staleness_of
- element_to_be_selected
- element_located_to_be_selected
- element_selection_state_to_be
- element_located_selection_state_to_be
- alert_is_present

```
results = self.driver.find_element(
    (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/h6"))
print(results)
```

I am not authorize to give the script because it is private, but could you help me? You could give a sample using "self.driver.element_to_be_clickable"

To get the text from any website

Comment: Hi Hans, this is not clear question. you need to elaborate more.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask